# Plot and report X intercept from linear regression - R

Tags: r, linear-regression, intercept

I am using `lm` in r for linear regression. I would like to plot and report the x intercept.  I know that I could use algebra and solve for x by setting y = 0, but is there a way to have r report it to me? Also, how can I 'tell' r to plot the x intercept?  Would this just entail extending the x axis range to include it?  Thanks.

```
# example r code
plot(y~x)
fit <- lm(y~x)
abline(fit)
```

Comment: You can get the intercept by doing `coef(fit)[1]`

Comment: In general, use `str` to see the real structure of a data object, i.e. `str(lm())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot the x-intercept, extend the plot as you said. You might need to extend it in both the x and y dimensions (use `xlim=c(0,100)` and `ylim=c(0,100)` or whatever), and you should note that R does not plot lines for the axes. I supposed you can add them in manually with `hline` and `vline` if you want.

To get the numerical value of the x-intercept, you'll have to do algebra.

```
> coef(fit)
(Intercept)           x 
  0.8671534   0.4095524
```

Gives the y-intercept and the slope, and you can easily find the x-intercept from there.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Oh, good catch. I obviously wasn't thinking clearly.