# Interpreting X intercept and slope parameter of model output of a log-log regression

Tags: r, parameters, regression, linear-regression, lm

A linear regression on dependent and predictor variable was run on simulated data after log transformation.

```
set.seed(12345) 
x <- rnorm(423, mean = 55, sd = 12)
y <- rnorm(423, mean = 1.44, sd = 0.3)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y))
mod <- lm (log(y)~log (x), data = dat)
summary(mod)
```

[summary output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfg8l.png)

Question:

Is the x intercept in this summary log 0.186 or 0.186? The slope estimate I think is 0.0424. Can this model written as follows::

logy = log 0.186 + 0.0424 logx

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about interpreting results from statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you log() an object/vector in R, it is in fact a natural log.

also note that the intercept is not transformed

so the resultant formula is actually:

ln(y) = 0.186 + 0.0424 * ln(x)

Comment: Thank you so much Hong for the reply. Somehow for the original dataset that I am working on, the intercept from the lm summary is positive (2.238), but when I plot the regression line using geom_smooth with method="lm", the line passes from x= -1.34. Is there a reason do you think? Souldnt the line pass the x axis at 2.238?

Comment: linear regression produces a model with the formula y = c + mx, the intercept output "c" is the y-intercept, not the x-intercept

Comment: Hi Hong, apologies, I did mean the y intercept. The line doesnt pass the y axis at 2.238.But I found the solution to this here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465275/plot-and-report-x-intercept-from-linear-regression-r